# FineUploader not uploading files

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am trying to upload files using FineUploader JS library. The problem is nothing gets uploaded to the required directory. I have my custom UI ready and I need to upload files using some form data too. I can't understand why it is not uploading and also how to get the progress data along with if the upload is complete.

In Console I get: `[Fine Uploader 5.16.0] Attaching to form element.`

**HTML**

```
<form id="uploadForm" type="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="inputBlock">
        <input id="heading" name="heading" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
        <span id="slide"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="previewContainer">
        <div id="preview">
    </div>
    <div id="overlay" class="hidden">
        <div id="checkmark" class="checkmark hidden">
            <div class="checkmarkCircle"></div>
            <div class="checkmarkStem"></div>
            <div class="checkmarkKick"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" class="hidden" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="user">
    <input id="snapBtn" type="button" value="CAPTURE" disabled>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#heading").on("change", function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) === "") {
            $("#snapBtn").prop("disabled", true).removeClass("btnEnabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#snapBtn").prop("disabled", false).addClass("btnEnabled");
        }
    });

    $("#snapBtn").on("click", function() {
        $("#fileUpload").click();
        return false;
    });

    $("#fileUpload").on("change", function(e) {
        $("#overlay").hide().css("height", "0");
        $("#checkmark").hide();
        var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
            debug: true,
            form: {
                element: "uploadForm"
            },
            request: {
                endpoint: 'functions/uploadHandler.php'
            },
            autoUpload: true
        });
    });
```

**PHP Snippet**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $error = "";
    $message = "";
    $name = filter_var($_POST["heading"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(empty($name)) {
        $error = "Please type your name..";
    }
    else {
        ...
```

Comment: what requests are you seeing on form submit?

Comment: All requests to page resources are being made except on submit the `uploadHandler.php` is not being requested.